# How to make bison not to show syntax error

Tags: bison

I have a part of my code that allows you to send an error, because when this error is showed, I'm gonna do something else.

How can i do to make bison not to print 'syntax error' while running it?

```
    s19 : s19tex otros CORTAR otros ROJO otros FINLINEA f3
    | s19tex otros CORTAR otros AZUL otros FINLINEA fdeath
    | s19tex otros CORTAR otros VERDE otros FINLINEA fdeath
    | s19tex otros CORTAR otros AMARILLO otros FINLINEA fdeath
    | s19tex otros EXPLORAR otros CELDA otros FINLINEA s15
    | s19tex otros FINLINEA snada s19
    | s19tex error FINLINEA serror s19
    ;

    serror : {printf("Casi... pero NO.\n");yyclearin;}

    ;
```

I just want the print of serror, not the syntax error

Answer (score 1):

The bison-generated parser doesn't print the error message. It calls `yyerror`, which is a function you must define. If you don't want the message printed, don't print it in `yyerror`